# Unity3D: Many gameObjects with few components vs. one gameObject with many components

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In implementing a service locater type of pattern, I'm wondering if either of these two approaches offer any kind of performance/logical improvements over the other.

My idea is that one `gameObject`, called "Game", would contain every service as a component (Audio, UI, AI) etc. Each component would then manage any child objects pertinent to that service, and spawn them as children of the main Game `gameObject`, calling the service like:

```
AudioService audio = gameObject.GetComponent<AudioService>();
audio.playSound("bang.mp3");
```

The alternative would be to instantiate each service as its own `gameObject`, and have another `gameObject` service locator which functions as a static point of reference to locate the relevant service:

```
AudioService audio = ServiceLocator.getAudio(); 
audio.playSound("bang.mp3");
```

Which is the better or more idiomatic approach in Unity? Is there any substantial difference between the two from a technical or logical standpoint?

Thanks!

Comment: I prefer the latter, because it segregates various systems into separate game objects in the editor and finding things is easy. Plus, if the need arises, I can add other related game objects as children of each system (e.g. the UI game objects can be the children of the UI manager game object), which helps logically separate things further.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @EvilTak!

Answer (score 0):

#### From a technical and performance side

**it does not matter.**

The difference consists in the GetComponent<>() vs GetComponentInChildren<>() query. Both will have to look up over a table, but the latter one will surely have to look over more objects. Their implementation is not specified by Unity.
The best practice is to cache them on start and avoid gathering components and gameObjects on Update.
**Use profiler**

#### From a logistical point of view

*It is up to your convenience.*
Personally I try to separate independant compoennt into several gameobjects.
When you have hard dependency, [RequireComponent] is a good practice to be sure that GetComponent works. It will force you to pack your component on one gameObject and even create them automatically.

If you want to require component in children, there is the OnValidate method to test manually in Editor mode without going into Editor GUI stuff.